# How to dynamically change color of element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, each

How can I change colors of elements using variables?

Let's say we have four strings(colors). I need to give every class element different one, 1,2,3,4,1,2,3... and so on:

```
function pressLineColors() {

    var a = "#eee",
    b = "#123",
    c = "#fff",
    d = "#ae23e5";

     $('.pressLine').each(function (i) {
         //go througt each of this, and give them colors, so when new elements
        // appear, give them next color. 
     });
}
```

First element sholud have color **a**, second **b**, third **c**, fourth **d**, and fifth **a**, ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function pressLineColors() {

    //setup array of colors and a variable to store the current index
    var colors = ["#eee", "#123", "#fff", "#ae23e5"],
        curr   = 0;

    //loop through each of the selected elements
    $.each($('.pressLine'), function (index, element) {

        //change the color of this element
        $(this).css('color', colors[curr]);

        //increment the current index
        curr++;

        //if the next index is greater than then number of colors then reset to zero
        if (curr == colors.length) {
            curr = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SngJK/

## Update

You can also use the suggestion in the comments to this answer to shorten the code a bit:

```
function pressLineColors() {
    var colors = ["#eee", "#123", "#fff", "#ae23e5"],
        len    = colors.length;
    $.each($('.pressLine'), function (index, element) {
        $(this).css('color', colors[index % len]);
    });
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SngJK/2/

## Update

You can also use `.css('color', function (){})` to iterate through each of the elements, returning the color you want to make the element:

```
$('.pressLine').css('color', function (index, style) {
    return colors[index % len];
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SngJK/4/

Comment: @jgauffin I rolled back because you removed my comments that explain the code. Also `$.each()` creates less overhead than `.each()` so I like to use it.

Comment: just use `colors[index % colors.length]` then there is no need for `curr`, `curr++` or the `if` block

Comment: Thought I'd post a JSPerf I made a while ago to demonstrate the different overheads for loops: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/7

Comment: @Kyle: it would just be `colors[index % colors.length]`.  `4 % 4 == 0`

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. `colors[index % colors.length]` seems like a good way to do it, I don't know the difference in performance but my guess is that it would be tiny either way.

Comment: Don't forget that you can pass a function argument to many jQuery methods... `$('.pressLine').css('color',function(i){return colors[i%colors.length];});` ...EDIT: Looks like you had just added it. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
function pressLineColors() {
  var a = ["#eee","#123","#fff","#ae23e5"];

  $('.pressLine').each(function (i, ele) {
    $(ele).css("color", a[i % a.length]);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

have these colors in an array

```
function pressLineColors() {

a = new Array();

a[0] = "#eee",
a[1] = "#123",
a[2] = "#fff",
a[3] = "#ae23e5";

var c = 0;
var size = a.length;

 $('.pressLine').each(function (i) {

      this.style.color = a[c];
      c++;
      if(c > size) c = 0;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a variable to keep track , and a separate function will allow you to add elements later and keep track

```
/* colors in indexable array*/
var colors=["#eee", "#123","#fff","#ae23e5"];

var counter=0;
$('.pressLine').each(function () {
         $(this).css('color', colors[nextColorIndex()]);

});

function nextColorIndex(){
    var ctr=counter;
         counter=(++counter <colors.length) ? counter++ :0
         return ctr;
}
```

Comment: you increase counter twice! `counter=(++counter < colors.length) ? counter :0`

Answer (score 1):

use    addClass

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

or

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

you need to put your list into an array-like object then access by index;

```
function pressLineColors() {

var colors = [ a = "#eee",
b = "#123",
c = "#fff",
d = "#ae23e5"];

 $('.pressLine').each(function (i) {
     //go througt each of this, and give them colors, so when new elements
    // appear, give them next color. 

   $(this).css("color" , colors[i]);
 });
}
```

Comment: Yes true, edited, also Jasper's and Kyle's answers are better because they allow for the size of the list and length of element array

Comment: and if there are more elements than colors?